# Which python core type is most efficient for in-list comparisons?

Tags: python, performance, processing-efficiency

The question is: in python, which data structure is most efficient for the reference set for inlist comparisons, i.e.

- There is a reference list of a relatively small number of items: count usually between 2 and 20
- There is arbitrary input data, usually millions of items (depending on different class instantiations)

I was wondering which data structures for the reference list is most efficient, and if there are trade offs based on the length of the reference list. For example, A dict key lookup is done in constant time, but I believe that the lookup cost is expensive compare to a indexed list lookup, and so I wondered if, for a 5-item reference list, the list would be more efficient.

I wrote a quick program to test this out, and so I'll answer the question myself, but interested in other thoughts and commentary.

Answer (score 0):

I built a program to benchmark this along the following criteria.

**tl;dr : Sets are consistently the fastest or tied for the fastest in all configurations.**

## Breakdown

- I considered a reference set of the following types: dict, list, tuple, and set
- I considered the size of the reference set for: 2, 5, 20, 50
- In case there were special efficiencies for strings, I modeled all strings and a mix of types (str, float, int, bool) evenly divided.
- I also  modeled cases in which all items in the data were in the reference and in which no * items in the data were in the reference list.

## Takeaways:

- To my surprise, sets were the most efficient (or tied) in every scenario.
- As expected, lists and tuples become increasingly less efficient for longer reference sets.
- At very small counts (n=2, n=5), lists are at times more efficient than dicts, especially for all strings when the vast number of items don't match.
- Checking the dict runs consistently slower when the items don't match than when they do match, which surprised me, especially because sets didn't have as much of a variation.

This was run with Python 3.7, on a Lenovo Yoga 910 with an i7 processor, 8gb ram, and Ubuntu 20.04

```
Summary:
    Len comparison: 2
    Len in: 10000000
    Len out: 10000000
    All strings: True
    Examples: ['@xj?', '@q^f_lv^m']

*** All In ***
    Dict: 0.53 s        (10000000 / 0)
    List: 0.51 s        (10000000 / 0)
    Set: 0.49 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Tuple: 0.51 s       (10000000 / 0)

*** All Out ***
    Dict: 0.82 s        (0 / 10000000)
    List: 0.63 s        (0 / 10000000)
    Set: 0.49 s     (0 / 10000000)
    Tuple: 0.64 s       (0 / 10000000)



Summary:
    Len comparison: 2
    Len in: 10000000
    Len out: 10000000
    All strings: False
    Examples: [5405, False]

*** All In ***
    Dict: 0.52 s        (10000000 / 0)
    List: 0.51 s        (10000000 / 0)
    Set: 0.49 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Tuple: 0.5 s        (10000000 / 0)

*** All Out ***
    Dict: 0.72 s        (0 / 10000000)
    List: 0.75 s        (0 / 10000000)
    Set: 0.6 s      (0 / 10000000)
    Tuple: 0.78 s       (0 / 10000000)

Summary:
    Len comparison: 5
    Len in: 10000000
    Len out: 10000000
    All strings: True

*** All In ***
    Dict: 0.48 s        (10000000 / 0)
    List: 0.67 s        (10000000 / 0)
    Set: 0.42 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Tuple: 0.65 s       (10000000 / 0)

*** All Out ***
    Dict: 0.92 s        (0 / 10000000)
    List: 0.89 s        (0 / 10000000)
    Set: 0.47 s     (0 / 10000000)
    Tuple: 0.88 s       (0 / 10000000)

Summary:
    Len comparison: 5
    Len in: 10000000
    Len out: 10000000
    All strings: False
    Examples: [394.761846741113, 'ih6ss(*-?n*{3(', 19425, True, 'c4npc*7;#uu|a!%*s5}']

*** All In ***
    Dict: 0.6 s     (10000000 / 0)
    List: 0.79 s        (10000000 / 0)
    Set: 0.53 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Tuple: 0.75 s       (10000000 / 0)

*** All Out ***
    Dict: 0.83 s        (0 / 10000000)
    List: 1.1 s     (0 / 10000000)
    Set: 0.6 s      (0 / 10000000)
    Tuple: 1.1 s        (0 / 10000000)



Summary:
    Len comparison: 20
    Len in: 10000000
    Len out: 10000000
    All strings: True

*** All In ***
    Dict: 0.5 s     (10000000 / 0)
    List: 1.4 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Set: 0.42 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Tuple: 1.4 s        (10000000 / 0)

*** All Out ***
    Dict: 0.95 s        (0 / 10000000)
    List: 2.2 s     (0 / 10000000)
    Set: 0.46 s     (0 / 10000000)
    Tuple: 2.2 s        (0 / 10000000)

Summary:
    Len comparison: 20
    Len in: 10000000
    Len out: 10000000
    All strings: False
    Examples: [10800, False, True, 2467.0373245526216, -175.42855370588768]

*** All In ***
    Dict: 0.59 s        (10000000 / 0)
    List: 1.4 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Set: 0.54 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Tuple: 1.3 s        (10000000 / 0)

*** All Out ***
    Dict: 0.84 s        (0 / 10000000)
    List: 3.1 s     (0 / 10000000)
    Set: 0.7 s      (0 / 10000000)
    Tuple: 2.9 s        (0 / 10000000)


Summary:
    Len comparison: 50
    Len in: 10000000
    Len out: 10000000
    All strings: True
    Examples: ['jz{>-ob*/b^fb)m7sbr&', '[1rs`b`y\\', 'l1--', '(.95', "6z|1!v_*,i_#'q/"]

*** All In ***
    Dict: 0.48 s        (10000000 / 0)
    List: 2.7 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Set: 0.45 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Tuple: 2.7 s        (10000000 / 0)

*** All Out ***
    Dict: 0.85 s        (0 / 10000000)
    List: 4.9 s     (0 / 10000000)
    Set: 0.54 s     (0 / 10000000)
    Tuple: 4.9 s        (0 / 10000000)

Summary:
    Len comparison: 50
    Len in: 10000000
    Len out: 10000000
    All strings: False
    Examples: [False, False, "$zdb+7!bs|5y?-'3__5", False, 814.9305661272301]

*** All In ***
    Dict: 0.59 s        (10000000 / 0)
    List: 2.9 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Set: 0.54 s     (10000000 / 0)
    Tuple: 2.7 s        (10000000 / 0)

*** All Out ***
    Dict: 0.85 s        (0 / 10000000)
    List: 7.0 s     (0 / 10000000)
    Set: 0.63 s     (0 / 10000000)
    Tuple: 6.7 s        (0 / 10000000)
```